# Error in RViz with vision_msgs/Detection3DArray visualization

Tags: ros, rviz, ubuntu, ros-noetic, rviz-plugins

I am trying to use the [Kukanani/vision_msgs_visualization](https://github.com/Kukanani/vision_msgs_visualization) plugin visualize the `vision_msgs/Detection3DArray` type of data.

I can add in RViz by display type `OrkObjectDisplay` option. But I get the following error, when I open RViz:

```
[ERROR] [1697653988.707062524]: PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 
'vision_msgs_visualization/OrkObjectDisplay' failed to load.  Error: Could 
not find library corresponding to plugin vision_msgs_visualization/OrkObjectDisplay. 
Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the 
library and that the library actually exists.
```

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! It seems that the package for `OrkObjectDisplay` is not found. Have you installed the dependencies?

Comment: @ravi Hello and thank you! I have cloned al the code that is in github. Would be enough with that, right?

Comment: Go to your ROS workspace and execute the command: `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y` it should install all the dependencies. If the problem persists, look at the package documentation, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error often happened to me when I built the package for the RViz plugin but did not source it in the terminal that starts and runs RViz.

Make sure you source the workspace where "vision_msgs_visualization" lives and run RViz in the same terminal.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late answer. I made **source devel/setup.bash** in my workspace and then run Rviz in the same terminal but I get the same error. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.  @Lewe

Comment: I also made **source ~/.bashrc** but no difference.

Comment: Hey @ARosOpenDR
Okay, did you also source the workspace of the plugins? In the bottom of the workspace(where src, install, build and log directories are) run `source install/setup.bash`
Then run rviz from there.

Comment: Hi, I don't have the install folder there so I couldn't do that. Instead, I did again **catkin_make** & **source devel/setup.bash** & **source ~/.bashrc** & Run Rviz in that terminal and now is working! Thanks for your help!